# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout I've tried everything I've tried to change the dependencies but nothing

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I've tried to change the dependencies and the style too, but still nothing is happening.

Any type of help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried this solution in the post but it's not working: [Error: Inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268546/error-inflating-class-com-google-android-material-textfield-textinputlayout)

Complete XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BmiActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bmi_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llUnitsView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_bmi_activity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilMetricUnitWeight"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/etMetricUnitWeight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="WEIGHT (in kg)"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilMetricUnitHeight"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/etMetricUnitHeight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="HEIGHT (in cm)"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llDiplayBMIResult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvYourBMI"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="YOUR BMI"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvBMIValue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="15.00" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvBMIType"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:text="Normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvBMIDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:text="Normal" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCalculateUnits"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="CALCULATE"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Complete Grade File:

```
       plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.a7miniuteworkout"
        minSdk 28
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 29
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Complete Manifest File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.a7miniuteworkout">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.7MiniuteWorkout">
        <activity
            android:name=".BmiActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Finish"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ExerciseActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Log Cat:

```
2021-06-28 20:21:53.466 22249-22249/? E/7miniuteworkou: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x800000
2021-06-28 20:21:53.613 22249-22249/com.example.a7miniuteworkout E/Config:Grabber:OnePlusFontConfig: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
2021-06-28 20:21:53.621 22249-22249/com.example.a7miniuteworkout E/7miniuteworkou: [frame_perf] perfboost open tb_ctl file failed, isApp[1], errno=No such file or directory
2021-06-28 20:21:53.622 22249-22249/com.example.a7miniuteworkout E/libprocessgroup: set_timerslack_ns write failed: Operation not permitted
2021-06-28 20:21:54.972 22249-22249/com.example.a7miniuteworkout E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.a7miniuteworkout, PID: 22249
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.a7miniuteworkout/com.example.a7miniuteworkout.BmiActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27 in com.example.a7miniuteworkout:layout/activity_bmi: Binary XML file line #27 in com.example.a7miniuteworkout:layout/activity_bmi: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3611)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3775)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27 in com.example.a7miniuteworkout:layout/activity_bmi: Binary XML file line #27 in com.example.a7miniuteworkout:layout/activity_bmi: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27 in com.example.a7miniuteworkout:layout/activity_bmi: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.a7miniuteworkout.BmiActivity.onCreate(BmiActivity.kt:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8006)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3584)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3775)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2246)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
2021-06-28 20:21:54.972 22249-22249/com.example.a7miniuteworkout E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:115)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:463)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:422)
            ... 30 more
```

Comment: Make sure you include your stack trace in the question. The title should be supplementary.

Comment: ok ive added it now @HenryTwist

Comment: As @javdromero has pointed out, you need to use a `MaterialComponents` theme. Your manifest shows you using an app compat one: `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`.

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this
> component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a
> descendant).

**1. If you are using a default theme:**

On your manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"
```

**2. If you are using a custom theme, it could be like:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Then call it on the manifest:

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

**3. You can add it directly to the view, e.g**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
...
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
...
>
```

Note:
It could be any variation like Light, Dark, etc. not always DayNight

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project

Comment: still the same error when I erase all the edit text stuff it runs perfectly

Comment: Edit your question and post the complete xml. There should be something else. the cause is clear. Also try point 3 on this answer.

Comment: ive added it please give it a look

Comment: Any of these 3 alternatives must work, make sure you are using them properly. I've run your xml and it works with what I've said in this answer..